# Hide some content types on Navigation portlet

Tags: plone

I'm overriding the Navigation portlet (following [this how-to](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/elements/portlet/override)) but after taking a look at the code I don't see any easy way to hide some elements based on my own criteria (right now would be by content type).

I assumed that just overriding the code and adding some code would be enough, but just [looking at the code](http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/portlets/navigation.py) made me realize that it isn't trivial at all, at least for me.

I ended up modifying the navigation_recurse.pt adding more conditions on a tal:condition, but it feels wrong somehow.

Is there a more friendly way to hide some content types to being displayed on the Navigation portlet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No code changes necessary at all.  SIte Setup -> Navigation -> Displayed content types.